# How do you make prisma redeploy to a database after you've removed all the tables from the database

Tags: prisma

I used prisma to generate the schema to a database, but due to changing an id column started getting errors. I deleted the tables and was going to redeploy the schema but I can't find a way to do that.

I've already tried doing things like prisma deploy, but it tells me I'm already sync'd up which isn't true. I need it to redeploy as if the schema was new and it seems to not want to do that.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**: Try `prisma delete` then `prisma deploy`.

Prisma create a database for `management` where it will hold all migration related data. Even if you deleted the tables manually, you didn't change the migration data about your service. Therefore, Prisma think everything is up-to-date.

Instead of manually deleting the tables, you should use `prisma delete` to let Prisma do a clean deleting of your tables. Then, you can re-run `prisma deploy` to rebuild the tables again.

Comment: prisma delete only delete the prisma service not database

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try: "prisma deploy --force"

According to the documentation you have to accept data loss caused by schema changes with --force. But the tables are already deleted in your case, so I think it is ok to try it.

[Prisma doc](https://www.prisma.io/docs/prisma-cli-and-configuration/cli-command-reference/prisma-deploy-xcv9/)